# Django. keep getting 404 on my images, don't know if i set up the paths right

Tags: python, django, static, django-templates, media

I'm trying to display images on a test website, i've already done it before

but now i've tried old and new sollutions since 3 days ago and keep getting 404 on my images. I have not set any static yet, just the media files.

Those are my models.py

from django.db import models

´´´´

```
     class Produto (models.Model):
        nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        preço = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
        foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.nome, self.foto)
```

´´´´

my settings.py

´´´´

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
    STATIC_ROOT = 'JR/JR/static/produtos'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

´´´´
´´´´

my views.py

```
       from django.shortcuts import render
       from.models import Produto


       def produtolist(request):
            list = Produto.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'produtos.html', {'list': list})
```

´´´´
and a pic with the error and paths:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L07SK.png)

and my template

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Produtos</title>
<!--   ------------links       -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"

</head>

<body>
  <h1>perdida</h1>
  <img src="/media/perdida.jpg" >
   <div class="cats">
  <ul>
      {% for Produto in list %}
          <li> {{Produto.nome}} - {{Produto.preço}}</li>
          <img src="{{ Produto.foto }}" alt="{{Produto.nome}}" />
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you display media (uploaded) files in your templates, you need to add the `MEDIA_URL` manually yourself preceding the file url. You can do that with the template tag `get_media_prefix`:

```
{% load static %}
...
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ Produto.foto }}" alt="{{ Produto.nome }}"/>
```

Note that by adding `upload_to="media"` in your `ImageField`, your images are uploaded to `/media/media/` directory, since that upload path is *relative* to `MEDIA_ROOT`.

If you need to use it in multiple places, like in your for loop, save some python lookups by doing:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_PREFIX %}
{% for Produto in list %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_PREFIX }}{{ Produto.foto }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thak you, so much sir, i've learned through ''new boston'' youtube channel and its a little bit old, for my next step i'd like to add videos in the same list  and after bring the foreign keys (detail templates) and auth users. do you recommend any tutorial or the documentation is the best one?

Comment: You know the official Django docs are really good, well structured with lots of examples. Spend most of your time reading them instead of looking for tutorials. But apart from that, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/ also has quite a few good examples.